# Facing syntax error while compiling Magento 2.4.4 setup, any fix?

Tags: installation, magento2.4.4

I am trying to create a new setup of Magento2.4.4 and followed the steps to get the repository.
Environment details : Used Ubuntu, Apache and PHP8.1.2
Facing issue while compilation

Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 149.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected token "<<"#0 /var/www/html/nagasestage/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(433): Composer\Autoload{closure}()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 /var/www/html/nagasestage/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#3 /var/www/html/nagasestage/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#4 /var/www/html/nagasestage/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#5 /var/www/html/nagasestage/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#6 /var/www/html/nagasestage/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#7 /var/www/html/nagasestage/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#8 /var/www/html/nagasestage/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#9 /var/www/html/nagasestage/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1021): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#10 /var/www/html/nagasestage/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(275): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#11 /var/www/html/nagasestage/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#12 /var/www/html/nagasestage/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#13 /var/www/html/nagasestage/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#14 {main}

Tried to reinstalltion
removed the vendor file and composer.lock file
Ran composer update which worked
Ran setup:upgrade it worked
While setup:di:compile I am getting this issue